# VBA - Referencing userform name from cell value variable

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am struggling to reference a userform name with a variable from cell.value located in range("A20").

Scenario: Double-clicking item in a listbox "completed missions" on userform "NewMission" opens up a "ReviewMission" userform.  This "ReviewMission" userform needs to be generic so that I can access it from whichever page I'd like after clicking on the same named listbox, carrying over the listindex of the selected value in the listbox - saved as "referencerow"

currently, the userform name is saved into a cell value, hoping to be later called back as the form of an object.

code:

```
Private Sub CompletedMissions_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

Worksheets("lists").Range("A20").Value = Me.Name 'saves the title "NewMission" to cell
ReviewMission.Show

End Sub
```

with the second form's initialize:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ListsSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range

ReferenceRow = UserForms(Range("A20").Value).CompletedMissions.ListIndex + 2
'CODE CONTINUES...
```

What am I missing here?  is there a way to use a public function?

Comment: What is it doing or not doing? is it giving you an error? Compile error or run-time error? what error? Where? You haven't really told us what the problem is.

Comment: This yields run-time error '380': could not set the value property. Invalid property value.     It works if instead of the userforms(range...) I replace it with newmission.completedmissions.listindex...      but I'm looking for a more generic solution that involves saving the string "newmission" and using it later as the object reference.

Comment: According to the MSDN VBA Visual Basic Language Reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264663.aspx), UserForms() only takes an integer value as an index. It's not like a regular collection. So maybe if you step through the collection and compare the name you can find the correct UserForm object.

Comment: You could set the form to be a public variable then just use it, so have `frmGlobal` and `set frmGlobal=new formOne` then hide it, use it in ReviewMission, and close.   Or add a property to your 2nd form, and set that from `me`